# How to get rid of libcurl linking error?

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl, linkage

I am using libcurl version 7.19 in my cpp application. I am trying to use the example given by [kukuruku.co](http://kukuruku.co/hub/cpp/a-cheat-sheet-for-http-libraries-in-c). When I try to build the application I am getting the following errror,

```
lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http_negotiate.o): In function `cleanup':
    http_negotiate.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `gss_delete_sec_context'
    http_negotiate.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `gss_release_buffer'
    http_negotiate.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `gss_release_name'

lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http_negotiate.o): In function `Curl_output_negotiate':
    http_negotiate.c:(.text+0x123): undefined reference to `gss_release_buffer'
    http_negotiate.c:(.text+0x1c0): undefined reference to `gss_release_buffer'

lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-http_negotiate.o): In function `Curl_input_negotiate':
    http_negotiate.c:(.text+0x324): undefined reference to `GSS_C_NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE'
    http_negotiate.c:(.text+0x33a): undefined reference to `gss_import_name'
    http_negotiate.c:(.text+0x48e): undefined reference to `gss_release_buffer'
    http_negotiate.c:(.text+0x4cc): undefined reference to `gss_release_buffer'
```

here is the code snippet I am using ,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My Makefile looks like this,

```
  CCFLAGS = -g -Wall -pthread -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -DUSE_APACHE2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -    O0 -ftemplate-depth-32 -fno-operator-names -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_GSS_C_NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE

  CFLAGS += `pkg-config --cflags libcurl`
  LDFLAGS += `pkg-config --libs libcurl`
  #DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
  #LIBS += -libcurl
```

I use module.mk file for the target,

```
APP_OBJECTS = \
        app-client/app-client-cmd.o \
    $(NULL)
```

Could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 6):

You should provide the linker options, e.g.

```
gcc -Wall -O2 -g -lcurl -o test main.cpp
```

Or use `pkg-config`. In a Linux shell it may look like the following:

```
gcc -Wall -O2 -g $(pkg-config --libs --cflags libcurl) -o test main.cpp
```

**UPDATE: static linking**

As **@drew010** suggested, you can generate proper linker options with
`curl-config`:

```
CC=$(curl-config --cc)
$CC -Wall -g -O2 main.cpp $(curl-config --static-libs) -o mytest
```

**UPDATE: added Makefile and CMake examples**

**Using Makefile**

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -O2
LDFLAGS =

EXECUTABLE = mytest
SOURCES = main.cpp

CFLAGS += `pkg-config --cflags libcurl`
LDFLAGS += `pkg-config --libs libcurl`


all: $(EXECUTABLE)


$(EXECUTABLE): $(SOURCES)
  $(CC) $(SOURCES) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)


.cpp.o:
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@


clean:
  rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

**Using CMake**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (MyProject CXX)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")

include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")

include(FindCURL)
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

if (NOT CURL_FOUND)
  message (FATAL_ERROR "Curl is not supported")
endif (NOT CURL_FOUND)

include_directories(CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS)

set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES "${CURL_LIBRARIES}")
list(APPEND LIBS "${CURL_LIBRARIES}")

set(TARGET "mytest")
add_executable(${TARGET} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} ${LIBS})

install(TARGETS ${TARGET} DESTINATION "bin")
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. I am using Makefile in a big application. How can use this in Makefile. Do I need to use CFLAGS?

Comment: @Dany It depends on your `Makefile` but use LDLIBS if it is compiling with implicit rules.

Comment: Based on the errors posted, he may also need to add `-lgssapi` as a linker flag as well.

Comment: @Dany Seems possible that the gssapi libs curl is linked against may be missing too.  Try `curl-config --static-libs` to see all it is linked against.  Then find libcurl and run `ldd /path/to/libcurl.so` and see if anything is missing.  You might need to install libgssapi-krb5-2 or other libgssapi libraries.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov - I added my makefile content here. But it is not working based on what I added :( . U guys are helping a lot. May be I am not understanding well. I am fairly new C/C++ and I am from Java background.

Comment: @Dany, try to use `curl-config --libs`(`--cflags`): `gcc x.cpp $(curl-config --libs) -o x` for dynamic linking, and `gcc x.cpp $(curl-config --static-libs) -o x` for static linking.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov - I use module.mk file for the target. I added the content in the question. yeah sure I will try this.